# C- Function that compares two four digit number arrays

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to create a function that compares two four digit numbers and
returns the number of similar digits between the two. For example, with a generated number of 4311 and the user entered 1488, 
the score should return 2 (4 and 1).

If it was 4311 and the other is 1147, 
the score should return three (1, 1 and 4). I don't know why it isn't giving me the right outputs, hope you can help.

```
int getSameDigitScore(int playerGuess, int generatedNum) {

    int score = 0;
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    int generatedNumArray[4];
    int playerGuessArray[4];

    // turns playerGuess into an array  
    while (playerGuess > 0 ) {
        i = 0;
        playerGuessArray[i] = playerGuess % 10;
        i++;
        playerGuess /= 10;
    }
    // turns generatedNum into an array
    while (generatedNum > 0) {
        i = 0;
        generatedNumArray[i] = generatedNum % 10;   
        i++;
        generatedNum /= 10;
    }
    // compares the two arrays  
    for (k = 3; k >= 0; k--) {

        for (j = 3; j >= 0; j--) {

            if (generatedNumArray[k] == playerGuessArray[j]) {
                score++;
                playerGuessArray[j] = 0;
                j = -5;
            }
        }
    }

    return score;
}
```

Comment: Can you pls post your current outputs/error messages?

Comment: What are you trying to do by  `j = -5`? Also isn't it better to set `playerGuessArray[j]` to something like -1 as 0 is a valid digit for your usecase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning `i = 0` inside the while loop while generating the playerGuessArray and generatedNumArray. Due to which the playerGuess and generatedNumArray array will have elements as `first digit of your number 0 0 0` . 
Move the initialization out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
int getSameDigitScore(int playerGuess, int generatedNum) {

    int score = 0;
    int i, j, k, n;
    int generatedNumArray[4];
    int playerGuessArray[4];

// turns playerGuess into an array  
    i = 0; // This has been out of while loop
    while (playerGuess > 0 ) {
        playerGuessArray[i] = playerGuess % 10;
        i++;
        playerGuess /= 10;
    }
// turns generatedNum into an array
    int n = 0; // This has been out of the while loop
    while (generatedNum > 0) {
        generatedNumArray[n] = generatedNum % 10;   
        n++;
        generatedNum /= 10;
    }
// compares the two arrays  
    for (k = 3; k >= 0; k--) {

        for (j = 3; j >= 0; j--) {

            if (generatedNumArray[k] == playerGuessArray[j]) {
                score++;
                playerGuessArray[j] = 0;
                j = -5;
        }
    }
}

return score;
}

int main() {
    int m;

    n = getSameDigitScore(1231, 2342);
    printf("Score is: %d\n", m);
}
```

You're re-initializing increment variable `i` on every iteration which should be moved out of the while loop. With that moved out the above code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

There are the following issues with the code.

- You are initializing the integer `i` inside the while loop. This needs to be done before the loop for each loop.
- You need a separate array to get the output of equal digits. See `AnswerArray` in code below. Also it is a good design practice to pass this array to the function and clear this array inside the function.
- In the last for loop, you should break from the inner loop after getting a match. This is to take care of cases where `playerGuess == 1222` and `generatedNum = 1111` In the code shown this will result in a `score` of 1.

See the final code below with some test cases.

```
int getSameDigitScore(int playerGuess, int generatedNum, int *AnswerArray) {

    int score = 0;
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    int generatedNumArray[4] = {0};
    int playerGuessArray[4] = {0};

    memset(AnswerArray,0,4*sizeof(int));
    // turns playerGuess into an array  
    i = 0;
    while (playerGuess > 0 ) {
        playerGuessArray[i] = playerGuess % 10;
        i++;
        playerGuess /= 10;
    }
    // turns generatedNum into an array
    i = 0;
    while (generatedNum > 0) {
        generatedNumArray[i] = generatedNum % 10;   
        i++;
        generatedNum /= 10;
    }
    // compares the two arrays
    score=0;
    for (k = 3; k >= 0; k--) {
        for (j = 3; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (generatedNumArray[k] == playerGuessArray[j]) {
                AnswerArray[score++] = generatedNumArray[k];
                playerGuessArray[j] = -1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return score;
}

int main(void)
{
    int AnswerArray[4],score;

    score = getSameDigitScore(4311,1488,AnswerArray);
    printf ("\nScore = %d \n Answer Array =  ",score);
    for (int i=0; i<score; i++)
    {
        printf ("%d ",AnswerArray[i]);
    }

    score = getSameDigitScore(4311,1147,AnswerArray);
    printf ("\nScore = %d \n Answer Array =  ",score);
    for (int i=0; i<score; i++)
    {
        printf ("%d ",AnswerArray[i]);
    }

    score = getSameDigitScore(1222,1111,AnswerArray);
    printf ("\nScore = %d \n Answer Array =  ",score);
    for (int i=0; i<score; i++)
    {
        printf ("%d ",AnswerArray[i]);
    }

    score = getSameDigitScore(1111,1222,AnswerArray);
    printf ("\nScore = %d \n Answer Array =  ",score);
    for (int i=0; i<score; i++)
    {
        printf ("%d ",AnswerArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The initializing `i=0` which you made inside the loop should be outside the loop.

```
    while (playerGuess > 0 ) {
        i = 0;
        playerGuessArray[i] = playerGuess % 10;
        i++;
        playerGuess /= 10;
    }
```

If the initialization is inside the looop then,

Everytime `playerGuessArray[0]` value will be updated.

FYI:

If playerGuess can contain `0` aat the begin of four digit like `0123`

For example, playerGuessValue is 0123, Then by using

```
while (playerGuess > 0 ) {
        i = 0;
        playerGuessArray[i] = playerGuess % 10;
        i++;
        playerGuess /= 10;
}
```

playerGuessArray will contain only `[1,2,3]` instead of `[0,1,2,3]`.

So, the better solution would be taking two temporary variables and checking last digit one by one.
Like this:

```
int temp1=playerGuess, temp2=GeneratedNum;
int i=0;
bool flag = true;
while(flag && i < 4){
  if(temp1%10 != temp2%10){
     flag = false;
  }
 temp1 /= 10;
 temp2 /= 10;
 i++;
}

if(flag){
  score++;
}
```

FYI:
Debugging will help you in finding out these little mistakes.So, try to debug your code with multiple inputs and verify your answer.

Here are few reference on how to debug:

https://blog.hartleybrody.com/debugging-code-beginner/

https://www.codementor.io/mattgoldspink/how-to-debug-code-efficiently-and-effectively-du107u9jh%60

Thanks.